# unable to retrieve option values from database using PHP in html

Tags: php

I am using the following PHP code to retrieve the team name from the mysql db table `team_details` which contains 2 columns,`team_id` and `team_name`

```
   <?php  
    mysql_connect("", "", "");
    mysql_select_db("db_name");
    $data = mysql_query("SELECT team_name FROM team_details");
    print "Team A:";
    Print "<select name="dropdown">"; 
    while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
    {  
    Print "<option value='".$info['team_name']."'>".$info['team_name'] . "</option> "; 
    } 
    Print '</select>'; 
    ?>
```

Full code

## Team and Players selection for the match

#### Choose the teams for the match

"; 
    while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
    {
    echo "".$info['team_name'] . " "; 
    } 
    echo ''; 
    ?>

```
VS 
Team B: 
<select id="team2" disabled="true">
<option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
<option value="saab">Saab</option>
<option value="opel">Opel</option>
<option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<button id="sub" disabled="true" name ="choose" onclick="load_players();"> Choose      Players</button>
<button type="reset" value="Clear" onclick="reset_load();"> Clear</button>
</form>

</div>
</body>
```

Comment: You must be getting a parse error actually.. Did you first fix that ?

Comment: add this to the top of your php file: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then check where the error is.

Comment: looks right if you fix the syntax errors

Answer (score 1):

you error may be here:

```
Print "<select name="dropdown">";
```

you need to escpae the double quotes:

```
Print "<select name=\"dropdown\">";
```

Comment: tried by escaping the double quotes but its still not working.. added the full code

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have syntax error here:

```
Print "<select name="dropdown">";
```

Escape quotes like this:

```
Print "<select name='dropdown'>";
```

Second, use [mysql_fetch_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) instead of mysql_fetch_array, so your code looks like this:

```
while($info = mysql_fetch_assoc( $data )) 
{  
    Print "<option value='".$info['team_name']."'>".$info['team_name'] . "</option> "; 
}
```

And check your mysql_connect in order to have right values (Host name, user, password)

Comment: I tried the way as you suggested but its still not working.. i tried most of the ways which are available over the internet but did not work.. I am pasting full code please have a look and suggest the solution to get over it. `code`

Comment: Add this in the beginning of the file:
`error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);` after `<?php`

And copy here any errors if occured. The only thing I can think of is bad mysql_connect call

Answer (score 0):

try following code, replace host, db_username, db_password and db_name

```
mysql_connect("host", "db_username", "db_password");
mysql_select_db("db_name");
$data = mysql_query("SELECT team_name FROM team_details");
echo "Team A:";
echo "<select name='dropdown'>"; 
while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
{  
echo "<option value='".$info['team_name']."'>".$info['team_name'] . "</option> "; 
} 
echo '</select>';
```

Comment: Issue still exists even after changing the code as given. I am gettig the below text in the webpage                                        "; while($info = mysql_fetch_assoc( $data )) { echo " "; } echo ''; ?>